# Android slideshow leads to Memory leaks

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I want to do an image slideshow on Android with only full sceen Images. No thumbnail (like in gallery), no zoom, no pinch. Only left/right slide to move from one picture to the other.

Pcitures are saved on the data folder and there are ~2000 pictures.

I use a full screen ViewPager for displaying the picures. Of course I can't load all the 2000 at once so I only load the needed picture when the user swipes to the corresponding view.

Each time the user swipes to a new viewPager position I call this code

```
public void onNewViewToDisplay(Integer newPosition, Integer previousPosition) {
    File file = functionToGetTheCorrespondingFile(newPosition);
    Bitmap bp;
    bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
    ((ImageView)imageAdapter.views.get(newPosition)).setImageBitmap(bp);
    if (previousPosition != null && previousPosition != newPosition) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = 
            ((BitmapDrawable)((ImageView)imageAdapter.views.get(previousPosition)).getDrawable());
        // Set the previous imageView to empty view
        ((ImageView) imageAdapter.views.get(previousPosition)).setImageResource(0);
        // Then free previous bitmap memory
        if (bitmapDrawable != null && bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

So I expect my code to always free the memory used by the previous displayed imageview.But when I look at my memory occupation

[image]

Leading to a memory leakage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Generate an hprof and look for what objects are increasing.  That will tell you what's leaking and help you find an answer.

Comment: Use glide or Picasso library

Comment: I tried to load the imageView with glide and exact same issue

Comment: As far as I know Glide and Picaso allows only galleries with thumbnails that we can click on. This is not what I want. I want only full screen images, no pich no zoom no thumbnails. Only swipe left/right. And user might swipe among the 2000 pictures on the disk.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the advice. I don't know how to intepret the results... For me conclusion is that bitmap is using all the heap. hprof screenshot : http://gangs-of-mafia.com/hprof.png alloc screenshot : http://gangs-of-mafia.com/alloc.png (Note: I use Picasso now but sale memory leak)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the reason why I add these memory leaks. This was because I had a reference to the `views` in my `PagerAdapter`.

You need to have no reference to the `views` and implement the `destroyItem` like this

```
public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    ((ImageView)object).setImageResource(0);
    BitmapDrawable bmd = (BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) object).getDrawable();
    if (bmd != null) bmd.getBitmap().recycle();
    View view = (View)object;
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView(view);
    view = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not efficient, because you create each bitmap every time the user swipes.

You should use LruCache to store the bitmaps so you don't have to re-create one that was already decoded.

Comment: You don't need to, you only add to the cache bitmaps that were decoded so if the user swipes back you don't need to re-create them.

Comment: OK but what about if the user swipes 2000 times? Then it's running out of memory

Comment: If the user swipes 2000 times it's a challenge buddy, what do you expect?
You should make some effort on it and check the available memory during the process and maintain it.

Comment: Yes maintaining available memory while the user swiped throught its picture gallery is exactly what I want to do. Question is how? I tried to make a bitmap.recycle but is not working.